# Trying to run flutter app on my android phone with the help of Android Studio but after it is installed: "Lost connection to device"?

Tags: android, flutter

I start the app:

[image]

It starts to install the app and after it is done... It opens & closes instantly:
[image]

This makes me impossible to debug the app while using a phone... (This test project is the default flutter project so it can't happen that some package broke the code...)

Anyone has any idea how to fix this problem? (I will need it to work because while my other project runs fine on emulator, it does not work on phone and I can't find a way to find why this happens if it keep losing connection...)

Answer (score 0):

Open the logcat to see if there's a more detailed error.

[image: logcat example]

Comment: Logcat is totally empty. Verbose, Debug, Info, Warn, Error or Assert... Every log is empty...